# Why doesn't "draw" increase by +1 in my rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spock?

Tags: javascript, html

The counter that counts the number of wins, losses and draws is working except for the draws counter. I have looked for a problem for about an hour now but I still can't figure out what is wrong.. Here is my complete code:

HTML:

```
<div id="you">
<span><h3>Your results:</h3></span>
<span>Wins:</span><span id="youWin"></span><br>
<span>Losses:</span><span id="youLoss"></span><br>
<span>Draws:</span><span id="draw1"></span>
</div>


<div id="center">

<button id="button" onclick="play()">Play</button>
<p>You rolled:</p><span id="myroll"></span>
<p>Your opponent rolled:</p><span id="opproll"></span>

<p id="outcome"></p>
</div>

<div id="opp">
<span><h3>Opponent's results:</h3></span>
<span>Wins:</span><span id="oppWin"></span><br>
<span>Losses:</span><span id="oppLoss"></span><br>
<span>Draws:</span><span id="draw2"></span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload=function () {
document.getElementById("youWin").innerHTML=" " + youwin;
document.getElementById("youLoss").innerHTML=" " + youloss;
document.getElementById("oppWin").innerHTML=" " + oppwin;
document.getElementById("oppLoss").innerHTML=" " + opploss;
document.getElementById("draw1").innerHTML=" " + draw;
document.getElementById("draw2").innerHTML=" " + draw;
}

var youwin = 0;
var youloss = 0;
var draw = 0;
var oppwin = 0;
var opploss = 0;

function play() {

var ROCK = 0;
var PAPER = 1;
var SCISSORS = 2; 
var LIZARD = 3;
var SPOCK = 4;

var choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'lizard', 'spock'];

var myRoll = Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length);
var opponentRoll = Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length);

document.getElementById("myroll").innerHTML=choices[myRoll];
document.getElementById("opproll").innerHTML=choices[opponentRoll];

if (myRoll == opponentRoll) {
document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML="It's a draw!";
return;
}

switch(myRoll) {

case ROCK:
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == LIZARD ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
if (opponentRoll == SCISSORS) {
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == SCISSORS ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
}
break;

case PAPER: 
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == ROCK ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
if (opponentRoll == SPOCK) {
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == SPOCK ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
}   
break;

case SCISSORS:
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == PAPER ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
if (opponentRoll == LIZARD) {
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == LIZARD ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
}
break;

case LIZARD:
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == SPOCK ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
if (opponentRoll == PAPER) {
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == PAPER ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
}
break;

case SPOCK:
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == SCISSORS ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
if (opponentRoll == ROCK) {
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == ROCK ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
}
break;

} //end of switch(myRoll)

var outcome = document.getElementById("outcome");

document.getElementById("youWin").innerHTML=" " + youwin;
document.getElementById("youLoss").innerHTML=" " + youloss;
document.getElementById("oppWin").innerHTML=" " + oppwin;
document.getElementById("oppLoss").innerHTML=" " + opploss;
document.getElementById("draw1").innerHTML=" " + draw;
document.getElementById("draw2").innerHTML=" " + draw;



if (outcome.innerHTML == "You win!") {
youwin = youwin + 1;
opploss = opploss + 1;
}

else if (outcome.innerHTML == "You lose!") {
youloss = youloss + 1;
oppwin = oppwin + 1;
}

else if (outcome.innerHTML == "It's a draw!") {
draw = draw + 1;
}

} //end of play()
```

I would have created a fiddle but it didn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this part:

```
if (myRoll == opponentRoll) {
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML="It's a draw!";
    return;
}
```

The `return` statement means that the execution of the function ends at that point, so `draw` is never increased. Probably easiest to take out that line and make the `switch` statement part of an `else` block.

With some other minor changes to reduce code that would look like this:

```
if (myRoll == opponentRoll) {
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML = "It's a draw!";
} else {
    switch (myRoll) {

        case ROCK:
            document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML = (opponentRoll == LIZARD || opponentRoll == SCISSORS ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
            break;

        case PAPER:
            document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML = (opponentRoll == ROCK || opponentRoll == SPOCK ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
            break;

        case SCISSORS:
            document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML = (opponentRoll == PAPER || opponentRoll == LIZARD ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
            break;

        case LIZARD:
            document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML = (opponentRoll == SPOCK || opponentRoll == PAPER ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
            break;

        case SPOCK:
            document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML = (opponentRoll == SCISSORS || opponentRoll == ROCK ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
            break;

    } //end of switch(myRoll)
}
```

Comment: Not sure how that code would look? Could u show it?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out :)

Comment: thx tho accepted ur answer and will prob make changes to reduce code too.

Comment: also I've been wondering if there is a similar syntax to "document.getElementById" but for classes?

Comment: @DuploW There's [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName), but there are some key differences. 1. Notice that the function name is plural - elements, not element. 2. It returns a collection of elements, so you can't set properties directly - you have to iterate through the collection. 3. It's backed by the DOM so dynamically updates; if you retrieve a collection of all elements with class X, then remove one of those elements, your collection will update automatically.

Answer (score 3):

From a **REALLY** quick look, I would guess it's because you are calling return if it's a draw so never getting to any of the later code.

```
if (myRoll == opponentRoll) {
  document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML="It's a draw!";
  return;  //<--- here
}
```

Comment: I need to have return there or it will count a draw as a loss. Doesn't work even if I remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning to break out of the draw case. This is skipping everything else. Change it to an if/else block(else being your switch for the win/loss conditions).